# Is there a detailed doxastic logic with a doubt operator?

Tags: logic, belief, doubt

I was "experimenting" with a doxastic logic with a doubt operator *D* besides the belief operator *B*, trying to come up with intuitive equivalences of interleavings (e.g. *DB*A = *BD*A, perhaps), but I couldn't find any more thorough literature to analyze. For example, Googling {"doubt operator" "logic"} gave me [this essay about a *deontic* doubt operator](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.00339.pdf), which goes too far beyond what I was thinking of. [This essay (clicking the link downloads it)](https://apcz.umk.pl/LLP/article/download/LLP.2020.014/26148/68501) mentions the notion in passing:

> An anonymous referee has pointed out that this is not a very interesting logic,
> because it only tells us that if we doubt a premise, we have to accept that we doubt
> it. She points out that, if one has a “doubt” operator in ones language, then some
> intuitively valid instances of it include “Jane is at the dentist; therefore, I doubt Jane
> is at the dentist”.

Maybe the rest of the essay addresses the idea, although when I did a search for the word "doubt" therein, only six results popped up, and no others with the phrase "doubt operator."

Weber[[09](https://rest.neptune-prod.its.unimelb.edu.au/server/api/core/bitstreams/ed584e81-9d11-5c96-b137-6c59b68f6c83/content)] says that Descartes used a doubt operator:

> ... [sometimes] diagonalizing leads only, harmlessly, to more objects. When diagonals
> meet totality, though, then fixed points result (c.f. §4 below).

> These fixed points can do, and have done, a lot of philosophical work; for example, Descartes famously used a doubt-operator, and came upon his cogito<sup>1</sup>:

> > I doubt(⌜ I am ⌝) iff I am.

But that is the only result for the phrase "doubt operator" in that entire 200+-page dissertation.

**Motivation:** in my "experiment," I tried cashing out, "I doubt that A," as, "I think that A doesn't close the question for which it is offered as the answer" (or at least, "I don't think that..."). But I wanted to be able to get to *DD*A = *B*A, or to avoid both doubt- and belief-explosions, and my erotetic cash-out doesn't seem directly pertinent to such equivalences or avoidances. But so for all that, I wonder whether a more detailed, already occurrent sample of doubt-operational doxastic logic would include intuitive analyses of such issues.

Comment: Beirlaen and Strasser introduced deontic logic with a doubt operator in [Structured Argumentation Framework for Detaching Conditional Obligations, pp. 12ff](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/A-structured-argumentation-framework-for-detaching-Beirlaen-Stra%C3%9Fer/e1a476b98aa66552a07f414e53903aeb9826b5f8). This is pretty much the only place I've seen it in any sort of formal way. [Rosa's discussion of doubt](https://philarchive.org/archive/ROSD-14) as a doxastic attitude may be of interest, but it is not formal. Typically, it is taken as ¬ B(p) ∧ ¬ B(¬ p).